# Moving an image in microsoft word using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to make an automated invoice maker and I currently am having difficulty positioning an image in a word doc using excel VBA

The image loads fine into the word document, yet it is the position that is causing me issues.

edit:
The specific issue that is causing is that the image is intended to be at the top of the page, but appears below the inserted text.

Thanks in advance for any help

```
Set wordObject = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'create the document object and add documents to it
Set documentObject = wordObject.documents.Add

'setting logo
Set logoObject = documentObject.inlineshapes



'make it visible
wordObject.Visible = True

'create selection object
Set selectionObjectHeader = wordObject.Selection

'place the logo
logoObject.AddPicture ("C:\Users\conno\Documents\logo.png")

With logoObject
    .ConvertToShape
End With

With caniprelogoObject.Shapes(1)
    .Top = 100
    .Left = 100
End With
```

Comment: What issue is it causing?

Comment: @richmichaels, I edited the problem, that should be more clear now. My apologies.

Comment: Why are you not using a template with the image already correctly positioned, plus any other content your documents always require? That way, your code could could be simpler, needing only to reference the template via wordObject.documents.Add

Comment: @macropod The task requires me to use excel VBA to create this entire project. Unless I can somehow insert a template into word using VBA, that is not a viable option.

Comment: Your use of wordObject.documents.Add already invokes a Word template - Normal.dotm. All I'm suggesting is that you use that to invoke your own template. When you say «The task requires me to use excel VBA to create this entire project», that suggests you want us to do your homework in some course of study...